# WordPress filter APPEND nofollow to rel

Tags: regex, wordpress, filter

I am trying append `nofollow` to add external links. If a link does not have a `rel` attribute, `rel="nofollow"` will be added. If a link already has `rel="nofollow"` nothing will happen, and if a link has `rel=something else` the `nofollow` value should also be added.

```
function nofollow($content) {
  $content = preg_replace_callback('/<a[^>]*href=["|\']([^"|\']*)["|\'][^>]*>([^<]*)<\/a>/i',
  function($m) {
    $parseUrl = parse_url(home_url());
    $mydomain = $parseUrl['host'];
    if (strpos($m[1], $mydomain) === false) {
      return '<a href="'.$m[1].'" rel="nofollow">'.$m[2].'</a>';
    } else {
      return '<a href="'.$m[1].'">'.$m[2].'</a>';
    }
  },
  $content);
  return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'nofollow');
```

The code successfully adds `rel=follow` to external links but if for a example a link has `rel="noopener" it will replace it will`rel=follow`. Why is it no appending like so?`rel="noopener nofollow"`

Answer (score 0):

Because you ignore all attributes of `<a>` tag except `href`. If you want to take existing `rel` value into account, you should read it also. And maybe it is easier to do with some html parser function, because regexp is a bit too low-level for your case.